# Issues adding and removing classes with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to have javascript add or remove the hidden class from `contact_form_top` when the button `contact_form_btn` is pressed, but I have not been able to make it work.

```
function hide_unhide_btn() {
if (document.getElementId("contact_form_top").classList.contains("hidden");{
    document.getElementById("contact_form_top").classList.remove("hidden");
}
else {
     document.getElementById("contact_form_top").classList.add("hidden");
}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change an element's class with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)

Comment: by the way, these things are much simpler/better with jQuery

Comment: Also it's getElementsByClassName()... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: There are at least 4 separate issues with your attempt (not counting matters of coding style). Start by using your browser's Developer Tools' Console to see what errors you are getting.

Comment: `document.getElementclassName` is not a function should be `document.getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: I've retracted my dupe-close vote.  Whilst the question linked does cover adding/removing/all sorts of other class based things, the code here as mentioned by others contains other issues too that are just as important to fix as the class part.

Comment: Where's your element with the class `"contact_form_btm"`?

Answer (score 2):

On a quick glance I see 5 problems in your code:

1. `element.className` is a String.

You can add a class to it with `element.className += " hidden"`. *Note the space* before the "hidden" word.

Without the space you will get className = "contact_form_tophidden" (one word = one class) instead of "contact_form_top hidden" (two classes)

2. Also you can't subtract a string by using `-=`,  subtraction is for numbers only.

Instead of manipulating the String className, I suggest you use `classList` which is an array-like list of classes that you can `add` and `remove`. If you want to be backward compatible with old browsers its best to use a framework such as jQuery or follow the className manipulation techniques described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/196038/519995

3. Also you need to use `getElementsByClassName` (uppercase *C*)
4. `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of elements, you need to iterate them with a `for` loop and modify the class of each, one at a time. Again, if you'd use a framework such as jQuery this would be much easier.
5. Also the `if` statement you are using will always enter the first part and never the second part, since the `content` is always "closed" when the function runs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.className` i suggest to use **[classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)** to easily mantain the add/remove classes, e.g :

```
if(content == "closed"){
    document.getElementsByClassName("contact_form_top")[0].classList.remove("hidden");
    content = "open";
}else if(content == "open"){
    document.getElementsByClassName("contact_form_top")[0].classList.add("hidden");
    content = "closed";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `classList` API for adding classes, which is very straightforward.

Here is an (unobtrusive) approach to adding and removing classes:

```js
function hide_unhide_btn() {
this.parentNode.classList.toggle('hidden');
}

var contactFormButton = document.getElementsByClassName('contact_form_btn')[0];
contactFormButton.addEventListener('click',hide_unhide_btn,false);
```

```css
.hidden {opacity: 0.1;}
```

```html
<form class="contact_form_top">
<input type="button" value="Contact Me" class="contact_form_btn" />
</form>
```